# Change hover class with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am exploring a way to to change the background colour of div OR change its class when a select box is checked. I can't figure it out because I can't understand what the best approach would be. I have replicated what I have done here: https://jsfiddle.net/c8qremy2/

```
<input type="checkbox" name="blue" value=".cp" id="cp"><label for="blue">Couch Potato</label>
```

So by checking the above checkbox is it possible to change the background colour of the below div:

```
  <div class="item cp sp cf bb" id="launDroid">
    <a href="" class="bgRed">
      <div class="content">
      <h2>Laundroid</h2>
      <p>Laundry That Does Itself</p>
      <div class="tileFooter">Category</div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

The background colour belongs to the to bgRed class. I am wondering if the above checkbox is selected it can change the bgRed class to say bgBlack which would be a black background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor the `change` event and update the rest of the DOM as you see fit. Also, the `for` attribute on your label should be the `id` of the `input` you want it to apply to, not the `name` attribute.

```js
$('#cp').on('change',function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
   $('.bgRed').addClass('bgBlack');
  } else {
   $('.bgRed').removeClass('bgBlack');
  }
})
```

```css
.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.item a{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.item:hover a.bgRed{
 background-color: rgba(232,43, 71, 0.9); 
}

.item:hover a.bgBlack {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="item cp sp cf bb" id="launDroid">
    <a href="" class="bgRed">
      <div class="content">
      <h2>Laundroid</h2>
      <p>Laundry That Does Itself</p>
      <div class="tileFooter">Category</div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  
  <input type="checkbox" name="blue" value=".cp" id="cp"><label for="cp">Couch Potato</label>
```

Comment: Thats almost what i am looking for but I would like the black to be the hover instead of the red but not replace the non hover background.

Comment: It does not seem to to work entirely on other checkboxes, I will show you and see if you could help me out?

Comment: @PhpDude if you have a new problem, you should make a new post. The comments section isn't a place for us to work through things outside of the scope of your question after you've already accepted an answer.

Comment: the issue with that is people start down voting. Marking it as a duplicate etc. Thanks for you help though Mark I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, jQuery can remove a class and replace it with another class:

```
$('a').removeClass('bgRed').addClass('bgBlack');
```

Comment: But how do I target that div, like what is the approach?

Comment: `$('#launDroid a').removeClass('bgRed').addClass('bgBlack');` would change the class of the a element inside the div, specifically. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Note that a shorter way of writing that is `toggleClass('bgRed bgBlack')`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I think you mean `toggleClass('bgRed', 'bgBlack')` http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: Meant what I said :). See the first overload *One or more class names (separated by spaces) to be toggled for each element in the matched set.*

Answer (score 1):

What you will need to do is set a watch for when the toggle is changed and then check whether or not the property is checked. You can do this with jQuery. I have updated the jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/c8qremy2/2/

Also refer to this question here to see how to check if a checkbox is checked with jQuery: [How to check whether a checkbox is checked in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-do-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery)

The jQuery (this makes the checkbox toggle the bg from black to white):

```
$('#cp').click(function() {
  if($('#cehcekc').prop('checked')) {
    $('.bgRed').css('background-color','#000');
  } else {
    $('.bgRed').css('background-color','#fff');
  }
});
```

Comment: That is not what I am after im afraid. I could get it to that point, however the objective is for when I am hovering it would be red, when the checkbox is checked the hover background colour becomes black.